# How kibana ui modules work?

Tags: angularjs, kibana, kibana-4

I read some kibana 4.3 source code. I think 'discover' controller is in 'apps/discover' module, how 'ui/routes' find it? which seems in 'kibana' module. thanks!

[discover.js](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/4.3/src/plugins/kibana/public/discover/controllers/discover.js)

```
var app = require('ui/modules').get('apps/discover', [
    'kibana/notify',
    'kibana/courier',
    'kibana/index_patterns'
]);

require('ui/routes')
  .when('/discover/:id?', {
    template: require('plugins/kibana/discover/index.html'),
......


app.controller('discover', function ($scope, config, courier, $route, $window, Notifier,
AppState, timefilter, Promise, Private, kbnUrl, highlightTags) {
......
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's about Angular, application level module 'kibana', which depends on the 'apps/discover' modules, so it can be found.